# List the top 10 that satisfy both the max value in one column AND the max value in the second column PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Having two tables with the following schema:

- `Population(country, population)`
- `Economy(country, GDP, poverty)`.

I have to find the top 5 countries in terms of the poverty rate and the GDP per capita (whic is GDP/population). I tried to solve this problem with the following query, but I don't know whether it returns me the right values:

```
SELECT
    A.country,
    A.GDP_per_capita,
    A.poverty
FROM (
    SELECT
        country(E."GDP"*1000000000)/P.PopulationGDP_per_capita,
        poverty
      FROM "Population" P
        NATURAL JOIN "Economy" E
    ) AS A
    JOIN (
            SELECT (E."GDP"*1000000000)/P.Population AS GDP_per_capita,
                    min(poverty) AS min_poverty
           FROM "Population" P
                NATURAL JOIN "Economy" E
           GROUP BY GDP_per_capita
           ORDER BY GDP_per_capita DESC
           LIMIT 5
    ) AS B ON A.GDP_per_capita = B.GDP_per_capita
              AND A.poverty = B.min_poverty
;
```

Is this query right?

Comment: By the way, when I was requested to find out the best 5 countries in terms of the poverty rate I suppose I have to find those with the lowest poverty rate, so in the query I have to change max(poverty) with           min(poverty)

Comment: There is an Edit button, you know.

Comment: I don't really understand. So, you want two queries: 1) "Top" 5 countries in terms of poverty. 2) Top 5 countries in terms of GDP/cap

Comment: Also. I don't understand why you have two tables.

Comment: I have to list the top 5 country terms of both of the following criteria: the percentage of people in poverty, and GDP per capita...

Comment: In the exercise's text the table are two...

Comment: The way you see if a query is giving you the right answer is to figure out what the right answer is, and then see if that's what the query says.  You can't shortcut that process.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no ties, I would expect to see something like this...

```
SELECT p.*
     , e.GDP
     , e.poverty
     . e.GDP/p.population gdp_per_cap
  FROM Population p
  JOIN Economy e
    ON e.something = p.something
 ORDER
    BY one thing or another thing
 LIMIT 5;
```